# Auto running a macro depending on day of the week

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to setup my workbook that will look at the day of the week and pull the appropriate macro for that day. For example I have 7 Macro's title by the day of the week, as it's a Wednesday, I want the wednesday macro to open when a user opens up the workbook.

I've got the following code but not sure where I'm going wrong...

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim sDate As String

sDate = Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy")

If Weekday(sDate, vbSunday) = 1 Then
Call SundayEfficiency
Else

If Weekday(sDate, vbMonday) = 2 Then
Call MondayEfficiency
Else

If Weekday(sDate, vbTuesday) = 3 Then
Call TuesdayEfficiency
Else

If Weekday(sDate, vbWednesday) = 4 Then
Call WednesdayEfficiency
Else

If Weekday(sDate, vbThursday) = 5 Then
Call ThursdayEfficiency
Else

If Weekday(sDate, vbFriday) = 6 Then
Call FridayEfficiency
Else

If Weekday(sDate, vbSaturday) = 7 Then
Call SaturdayEfficiency
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You haven't said *what* is going wrong.  What happens with your code at the moment?

Comment: Ah my apologies. It's doing nothing to be exact. I save the VBA, then reload the sheet but it hasn't run today's Macro.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with the way you have structured your code. If I indent your code, your code will look like this

```
If Weekday(sDate, vbSunday) = 1 Then
    Call SundayEfficiency
Else
    If Weekday(sDate, vbMonday) = 2 Then
        Call MondayEfficiency
    Else
        If Weekday(sDate, vbTuesday) = 3 Then
            Call TuesdayEfficiency
        Else
            If Weekday(sDate, vbWednesday) = 4 Then
                Call WednesdayEfficiency
            Else
                If Weekday(sDate, vbThursday) = 5 Then
                    Call ThursdayEfficiency
                Else
                    If Weekday(sDate, vbFriday) = 6 Then
                        Call FridayEfficiency
                    Else
                        If Weekday(sDate, vbSaturday) = 7 Then
                            Call SaturdayEfficiency
                        End If
```

The first problem you will experience with the above code is that you will have to add `End If` for each `If`

What you actually want is

```
If Weekday(sDate, vbSunday) = 1 Then
    Call SundayEfficiency
ElseIf Weekday(sDate, vbMonday) = 2 Then
    Call MondayEfficiency
ElseIf Weekday(sDate, vbTuesday) = 3 Then
     Call TuesdayEfficiency
ElseIf Weekday(sDate, vbWednesday) = 4 Then
   '
   '~~> And so on...
   '
End If
```

Alternatively you can use `Select Case`

```
Select Case Weekday(Date, vbSunday)
    Case 1: SundayEfficiency
    Case 2: MondayEfficiency
    Case 3: TuesdayEfficiency
    '
    '~~> And So On
'
End Select
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/weekday-function) for the `Weekday()` function, you will see that the second parameter sets which day of the week it should treat as the first day.  So calling `Weekday(sDate, vbTuesday)` will return 1 for Tuesday, 2 for Wednesday, etc.

Therefore the only time your code will work properly is on a Sunday.  On a Tuesday it will run `MondayEfficiency`, as Tuesday is the second day of the week if you set the first day of the week as `vbMonday`.  On a Wednesday it will run `FridayEfficiency` as Wednesday is day 6 if you start on Friday.

There are a few other things that could be improved while we're at it: `Weekday()` can take a date serial value so there is no need to convert to a string; and a case statement is more efficient and readable here.

Putting it together:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Select Case Weekday(Date, vbSunday)
        Case 1
            Call SundayEfficiency
        Case 2
            Call MondayEfficiency
        Case 3
            Call TuesdayEfficiency
        Case 4
            Call WednesdayEfficiency
        Case 5
            Call ThursdayEfficiency
        Case 6
            Call FridayEfficiency
        Case 7
            Call SaturdayEfficiency
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense, it compiles fine but when I load the workbook up now it brings back an error 'Compile error in hidden module: Module 6. This error commonly occurs when code is incompatible with the version, platform, or architecture of this application'. I'm using Excel version 2016.

Comment: You'll need to create a new question for that.  Googling the error message brings up a few hopeful-looking leads though.